# How to add sqlite3 comands on a make

Tags: sqlite, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile where i can configure automatically the headers and the columns of the sqlite3 terminal so every time i execute the makefile i don't have to put manually:

.headers on
.mode columns

Here i drop my makefile:

```
name = empleats
prefix = sqlite3

prebd = $(name).bd
presql = $(name).sql

all: convertbd openbd configure clean

bd: convertbd openbd

convertbd:
    $(prefix) $(prebd)< $(presql)
    
openbd:
    $(prefix) $(prebd)

configure:
    .mode columns
    .headres on


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.bd
```

Comment: IIRC, each make command is run in a separate process, so you will have to run `openbd` and `configure` in a single command, like so: `printf '.mode columns\n.headers on' | $(prefix) $(prebd)` if you don't want to store the configure statements in an external file

Answer (score 0):

Well to make this i found a solution and it was creating a .sqliterc file in my home directory where i added this two lines and saved the file, so every time i run sqlite3 in my terminal i have those config lines already there.

```
.headers on
.mode columns
```